# how to reverse digits of a real no?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

i know to reverse the digits of a number(integer) in c but my questions is how can we reverse the digits of a real no 
for e.g 1200.23 gets reversed as 32.0021

code for integers

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Iterative function to reverse digits of num(integer)*/
int reversDigits(int num) 
{
  int rev_num = 0;
  while(num > 0)
  {
    rev_num = rev_num*10 + num%10;
    num = num/10;
  }
  return rev_num;
}

/*Driver program to test reversDigits*/
int main()
{
  int num = 4562;
  printf("Reverse of no. is %d", reversDigits(num));

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Convert to string, reverse string, convert back to float if necessary.

Comment: This looks dangerous to me. 1200.23 is very close to 1200.230001, but 32.0021 is a very long way from 100032.0021. What do you plan to use it for? Not to fly aeroplanes, I hope.

Comment: The title made it look like it was going to be about actual Reals, most of which have an infinitely long decimal expansion. Reversing them in this way would give .. trouble.

Comment: @TonyK: I don't think there is a practical use for reversing digits.

Comment: @TonyK: Worse than that, the exact values of float cannot be either .23 or .23001. While all float values can be expressed exactly in decimal (decimal shares a factor 2 with binary), this generally be done in 7 digits.

Comment: Not going to work because of floating point error. Unless you're okay with passing around everything as a string.

Comment: i was asked to reverse digits of a integer in interview for eg 100 reversed as 001 using stack n above logic but then this question came to my mind what if number is a real no.

Comment: @prajmus: I'm not sure that you should have removed the `C++` tag - my guess is that the OP is happy to get answers using either C or C++ (since this is how he tagged the question), and by removing this tag you have now invalidated a perfectly good answer (see below).

Comment: @PaulR in question he specifically stated that he knows how to reverse it in C and he uses C code only, my guess was he added C and SO suggested C++ as new tag which he added. I may be wrong but it happens a lot of times (C questions tagged C++)

Comment: @prajmus: no, he says he knows how to do it for an `int`. Also see the comments to the C++ answer below, where he is asking for help compiling the C++ example.

Comment: "Reversing the digits of an integer" is actually a wrong interpretation. You are not reversing the *digits* ('reversing' is a reversable operation, and while "123" yields" "321", which is reversable, "100" to "001" *as integer* is not -- you would get `1`). Instead, you are reversing the **string** that forms the integer. The fact that you can do that with an integer without first making it a string is a mere footnote. If you have a general string reverse function, you can use it for integers as well as for floating point numbers. The question is then how many significant digits you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your paramater needs to be floating point type.

You could convert double to string then reverse the string then convert back to double:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
std::string toString(T t)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    rteurn ss.str();
}

double reversDigits(double num)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(num);
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());


    double d;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> d;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: which library for to_string()

Comment: m getting this error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni it's not hard to write another toString function, see my update.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni" you need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: yeah i did but it shows same error for reverse @TonyK

Comment: can't we convert it to character array @billz

Comment: does it has something to do with online compiler ?

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment: you are using c++11 compiler right? also show me the link

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php             this one is c++11 compiler

Comment: well i got the idea that is to use power of "stringstream"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code, where the iostream library is being used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double pass = 0;
    double n;
    double result=0;

    cout << "Please enter a number to reverse" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    while (trunc(n / pow(10.0, pass)) > 0) {

        result = fmod((n / pow(10.0, pass)), 10.0);
        cout << trunc(result);
        pass = pass + 1;

    }

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

This uses the methods (12345/10), which gives you 1234.5 which then truncates into 1234. The above code also use the modulo method ('%' is the operator for modulo). For example, if you do 12345 % 10, the program displays the remainder of 12345/10, which in this case, would be 5.

I used this method in a loop to get the desired output.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I MADE THIS PROGRAM FOR A CLASS, SO IF THIS IS NOT EXACTLY WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR, KINDLY DISREGARD THIS POST.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

float reversDigits(float num)
{
  char buffer[20],ch,*ptr;
  int i,j,len;
  snprintf(buffer,20,"%.3lf",num);
  len = strlen(buffer);
  for(i=0,j=len-1;i<j;i++,j--)
  {
        ch=buffer[i];
        buffer[i]=buffer[j];
        buffer[j]=ch;
  }
  buffer[len] = '\0';
  return atof(buffer);
}

int main()
{
  float num = 45000.062;
  printf("Reverse of no. is %.5lf\n", reversDigits(num));

  return 0;
}
```

Am passing a number with 3 digits after `.`, so i am using `%.3lf` in `snprintf`, if you simply use `%lf` means, while converting it to string it will add zeros and some numbers. To avoid that am using, else you need to do a little bit of more work to remove it!

Note: while converting string to float else float to string, in decimal position it will add some extra number or zero. The programmer need to take care of it!

Comment: for d code it is printing "Reverse of no. is 260.000549"

Comment: try the edited code! else use `%.5lf` in printf of main! This is the big problem with float number!

Comment: Reverse of no. is 260.00055

Comment: For exact values design your own `atof` function!